# Dictionary changing size during iteration and I don't know why

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nltk

Here's the error message:

> RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Here's the segment of my code (<= marks the error line):

```
# Probability Distribution from a sequence of tuple tokens
def probdist_from_tokens (tokens, N, V = 0, addone = False):
    cfd = ConditionalFreqDist (tokens)
    pdist = {}

    for a in cfd:  # <= line with the error
        pdist[a] = {}
        S = 1 + sum (1 for b in cfd[a] if cfd[a][b] == 1)
        A = sum (cfd[a][b] for b in cfd[a])

        # Add the log probs.
        for b in cfd[a]:
            B = sum (cfd[b][c] for c in cfd[b])
            boff = ((B + 1) / (N + V)) if addone else (B / N)
            pdist[a][b] = math.log ((cfd[a][b] + (S * boff)) / (A + S))

        # Add OOV for tag if relevant
        if addone:
            boff = 1 / (N + V)
            pdist[a]["<OOV>"] = math.log ((S * boff) / (A + S))

    return pdist
```

I'm basically just using cfd as a reference to put the correct values in pdist. I'm not trying to change cfd, I just want to iterate over it's keys and the keys of it's sub dictionary.

I think the problem is caused by the lines where I set the variables A and B, I got the same error when I had different code on those lines but I don't get the error when I replace them with a constant value.

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained example demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 1):

[`nltk.probability.ConditionalFreqDist`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html#nltk.probability.ConditionalFreqDist) inherits [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), which means if you read a non-existing entry `cfd[b]`, a new entry `(b, FreqDist())` will be inserted to the dictionary, and thus changing its size. Demonstration of the problem:

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(int, {'a': 1})
for k in d:
    print(d['b'])
```

Output:

```
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 4, in <module>
    for k in d:
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

---

So you should check this line:

```
    for b in cfd[a]:
        B = sum (cfd[b][c] for c in cfd[b])
```

are you sure the `b` key really exists in `cfd`? You may want to change it to

```
        B = sum(cfd[b].values()) if b in cfd else 0
#                                ^~~~~~~~~~~
```